# How do we capture lock screen of Windows/Mac using webrtc

Tags: windows, go, webrtc, chromium, darwin

I am working on a webrtc app & would like to know if there is a  way to capture lock screen and allow user login/logout of windows & Mac systems.Right now I run it as an Application from User context & it doesn't have privileges to access lock screen. Any insights here would be of much helpful to me.